# Extract sentence embeddings features with Pandas and spaCy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I'm currently learning spaCy, and I have an exercise on word and sentence embeddings. Sentences are stored in a pandas DataFrame columns, and, we're requested to train a classifier based on the vector of these sentences.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|   |                                          sentence |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
| 0 | "Whitey on the Moon" is a 1970 spoken word poe... |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | St Anselm's Church is a Roman Catholic church ... |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | Nymphargus grandisonae (common name: giant gla... |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Next, I apply an NLP function to these sentences:

```py
import en_core_web_md
nlp = en_core_web_md.load()
df['tokenized'] = df['sentence'].apply(nlp)
```

Now, if I understand correctly, each item in df['tokenized'] has an attribute that returns the vector of the sentence in a *2D* array.

```py
print(type(df['tokenized'][0].vector))
print(df['tokenized'][0].vector.shape)
```

yields

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(300,)
```

How do I add the content of this array (300 rows) as columns to the `df` dataframe for the corresponding sentence, *ignoring stop words*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using a single value averaging all vectors does yield good results in a classification model. What was needed was indeed a dataframe of 300 columns per sentence (since 300 is the standard length of spaCy word embeddings:

So, to continue @Sergey's code:

```py
sents = ["'Whitey on the Moon' is a 1970 spoken word"
         , "St Anselm's Church is a Roman Catholic church"
         , "Nymphargus grandisonae (common name: giant)"]

df=pd.DataFrame({"sentence":sents})

df['tokenized'] = df['sentence'].apply(nlp)
df['sent_vectors'] = df['tokenized'].apply(lambda x: x.vector)
vectors = 0['sent_vector'].apply(pd.Series)
```

With this, `vectors` contains the features of which a model can be trained. For instance, assuming each sentence has a sentiment attached to it:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = vectors
y = df['sentiment']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

What I couldn't do is to remove stopwords from the DataFrame entries (i.e. remove each `Token` object from the `Doc` parent object stored in the dataframe where `is_stop` is `False`.

Answer (score 5):

Assume you have list of sentences:

```
sents = ["'Whitey on the Moon' is a 1970 spoken word"
         , "St Anselm's Church is a Roman Catholic church"
         , "Nymphargus grandisonae (common name: giant)"]
```

that you put into a dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"sentence":sents})
print(df)
                                        sentence
0     'Whitey on the Moon' is a 1970 spoken word
1  St Anselm's Church is a Roman Catholic church
2    Nymphargus grandisonae (common name: giant)
```

Then you may proceed as follows:

```
df['tokenized'] = df['sentence'].apply(nlp)
df['sent_vectors'] = df['tokenized'].apply(
  lambda sent: np.mean([token.vector for token in sent if not token.is_stop])
                                          )
```

The resulting `sent_vectorized` column is a mean of all vector embeddings for tokens that are not stop words (`token.is_stop` attribute).

**Note 1**
What you call a `sentence` in your dataframe is actually an instance of a `Doc` class.

**Note 2**
Though you may prefer to go through a pandas dataframe, the recommended way would be through a getter extension:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")

sents = ["'Whitey on the Moon' is a 1970 spoken word"
         , "St Anselm's Church is a Roman Catholic church"
         , "Nymphargus grandisonae (common name: giant)"]

vector_except_stopwords = lambda doc: np.mean([token.vector for token in sent if not token.is_stop])
Doc.set_extension("vector_except_stopwords", getter=vector_except_stopwords)

vecs =[] # for demonstration purposes
for doc in nlp.pipe(sents):
    vecs.append(doc._.vector_except_stopwords)
```

Comment: Thanks! I presume this yields a single feature per sentence (mean of the sentence vector). Is that enough to train a classifier model?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to classify a sent or a doc. This is a bit different to what you asked: one column for a non stop word. Finding a single doc embedding through mean averaging (or tfidf averaging) is the way to go with word embeddings. This is different to other bag of word models like counts or ohe or vanilla plain tfidf.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the explanation. I thought I needed to extract 300 features as columns.

Comment: @mrgou Does it answer your question? Was it helpful? Please consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers